# Applying apply to a function w multiple parameters

Tags: r, apply

I want to use the `apply` function to the `train` function in the `caret` package.

The `train` function requires three parameters `a`, `b` and `c`.  For my purposes `a` and `b` do not vary, but I'd like to iterate over many values of `c` which are contained in a vector.

How can I use `apply` (or one of its cousins) to do this storing the results in a list (or other structure)? I've read the documentation and have used `apply` to find row and column means.  But, mean only requires 1 parameter.  I have three.  Also, my `b` parameter is a large data frame.  I've thought about replicating `a` and `b` for each `c`, but this seems wasteful.

Comment: Welcome to So.  This question is not formatted in a way that is friendly to answer or friendly for future searchers.  Could you make some modifications after reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lapply( c.vector, train, a=1, b=2)
```

Obviously I am guessing at values for `a` and `b`, but the principle should be clear. The `...` argument mechanism allows you to supply *named* fixed parameters to functions called with `lapply` or `sapply`, or `apply`. The problem with using `apply` is that it expects a matrix or datafrrame argument and that can be unwise since the row vectors will get coerced to the lowest common denominator class, often "character"